# Remove all the items of Infragistics UltraListView in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics

I have a `ultraListView` and i want to remove all the value of it in a method.
I am using Infragistics UltraListView in C#.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Items](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2013.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinListView.v13.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinListView.UltraListView~Items.html) property of the [UltraListView](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2013.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinListView.v13.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinListView.UltraListView_members.html) is an [UltraListViewItemsCollection](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2013.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinListView.v13.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinListView.UltraListViewItemsCollection_members.html) which can be cleared:

```
listView.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: Note you never gave any version information so your mileage may vary.